# Vertical Paging Transition of Sections: HTML, CSS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm not sure if "vertical paging transition" is exactly the right term for the transition I am looking for. The transition between HTML sections I want is imagine a stack of papers and you pull the top sheet off vertically revealing the one below and then repeat for each section.

Can some give me the proper term for this transition or point me in the direction of an example? Thanks!

edit: example  http://vascore.org

Comment: Are you referring to... scrolling?

Comment: What, like this: http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs/4

Comment: @TylerH like this http://www.vascore.org

Comment: @badger0053 You could absolutely position all your elements in the same space, then give them all different `z-index` values, so that they stack on top of one another, and then use JavaScript to slide them up on scroll or button click or some other event.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sometimes referred to as "parallax"

http://www.devfloat.com/jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/

It's perhaps a "vertical slide deck with a parallax transition between slides".

Edit:

That link has a few different tutorials, so here's one (from said link) that I believe is very close to what you're referring to:

http://chrisspooner.com/my-sites/

and the tutorial:

http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-cool-website-with-fancy-scrolling-effects

Comment: That's kind of what I'm looking for. I thought parallax was the background moving separately than the content. What I really want is the content and the background to move together, but "loaded" underneath the current section

Comment: I disagree; parallax in web development is two elements moving at different speeds relative to each other (usually the foreground element moves faster than the background element to simulate distance). Here I believe the OP is simply asking for a static background and a vertically moving foreground.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, but each section has a different background and content

Comment: While I agree that the term "parallax" has been potentially overused, that is why I put it in quotes. The link I provided has examples that span a variety of techniques. I don't agree, at all, with your assertion that the OP wants a "static background", because I looked at the example site provided.